# Is there a DHCPv6 equivalent of DHCPv4's private-use options?

Tags: dhcpv6

DHCPv4 allows for custom information to be provided to network devices, using "private-use" options. The [IANA registry of DHCP parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml) reserves option numbers 224 to 254 for private use.

Does DHCPv6 have an equivalent of DHCPv4's private-use options? I can't see any in the [IANA registry of DHCPv6 parameters](https://www.iana.org/assignments/dhcpv6-parameters/dhcpv6-parameters.xhtml).

I found a draft [Site Specific Options for DHCP for IPv6](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-volz-dhc-dhcpv6-site-options-00) which proposes site-specific options, but says they must not be used for vendor-specific options.

One possible usage scenario is, I'm interested in making a network device which can automatically get a server address for a custom IP protocol. So the DHCPv4 private-use option seemed like a possible avenue for the device to request the server address, and the DHCP server to provide it.

Comment: Nothing that I could find. But you could probably get away with using the highest numbered options. If you are really creating new DHCPv6 options, read [RFC 7227](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7227) first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After investigating this further myself...

It would be better to use **vendor-specific options** rather than private-use options. (Eg I'm interested in making a network device which can query the DHCP server for a server address for a custom IP protocol.)

For DHCPv4:

- (Inspired by the DHCPv6 options 16 and 17; see below) Clients can report [option 124 Vendor-Identifying Vendor Class](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3925#section-3). Servers can reply with [option 125 Vendor-Identifying Vendor-Specific Information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3925#section-4).
- (Older method, not as well-specified) Clients can report [option 60 vendor class identifier](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-9.13). Servers can reply with [option 43 vendor-specific info](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-8.4).

For DHCPv6:

- Clients can report [option 16 vendor class](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-21.16) containing a [private enterprise number](https://www.iana.org/assignments/enterprise-numbers/enterprise-numbers). Servers can reply with [option 17 vendor-specific info](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8415#section-21.17).

For many DHCPv4 and DHCPv6 servers, it is most likely necessary to configure the option by specifying it as a binary data string, entering the data as hex digits. I found the following configuration examples:

- [(Microsoft) Vendor specific DHCP options explained and demystified - Ingmar Verheij](https://www.ingmarverheij.com/microsoft-vendor-specific-dhcp-options-explained-and-demystified/) which talks about DHCPv4 options 60 and 43.
- [Configure Option 125 on a Server to Allow Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) Auto Image Updates on a Switch - Cisco](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/switches/cisco-small-business-200-series-smart-switches/smb5328-configure-option-125-on-a-server-to-allow-dynamic-host-confi.html)